# RowIndex' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs

Tags: vb.net

in my datagridview 
in `CellEndEdit` event I wrote code like this:

```
DGVall.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange
```

This time the code is working fine.
but i try to give the same code in my gridview `DGVall_KeyDown`
That Time showing `error:RowIndex' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs`
instead of that code i can give any other code getting same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the **sender** not the eventargs

```
Private Sub MyDatagridview_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyDatagridview.KeyDown

    Dim dgv As DataGridView = CType(sender, DataGridView)

    Dim rowindex As Integer = dgv.SelectedRows(0).Index

End Sub
```

MyDatgridview is the the name of my DataGridView.

Comment: sir..in my case how i can give,Ctype(sender,here(my datagridview name is not showing)

Comment: DataGridView in CType is the type DataGridView not your control. sender is your control.

Comment: DGVall.Rows(CType(sender, after this what i have to give?

Comment: DGVall.Rows(CType(sender, DataGridView)).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange ..what is wrong with this code?

Comment: this would be your control in the given sub. you need to access the rowindex if you want to use that

Comment: sir..i am not getting what you are trying to say..can you give some more explanation?

Comment: Think now it should be clear. In that sub you can now access the Datagridview by the dgv var and the the selectrowindex

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is pretty self-explanatory, the variable `RowIndex` doesn't exist in the type `KeyEventArgs`.  If you look at the method' signature, you'll see that it's not the same.

[`CellEndEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit.aspx) sample

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                         ByVal e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) _
Handles dataGridView1.CellValidating
```

[`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) sample

```
Private Sub textBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
 Handles textBox1.KeyDown
```

The `KeyDown` event is inherited directly from `Control`, and has no idea about the row you're in (which is directly from the `DataGrid` control).

However, the `sender` argument of the `KeyDown` event should be a DataGridCell, so you can cast it to access the rown number.

Comment: See the answer of @DavidSdot, it's more complete than mine.